# Does anyone know where to find the datasheet for an Electrocraft Model E19-2 motor?

Tags: motor, datasheet

More details from the motor casing:

- Electrocraft
- Model: E19-2
- Serial: A01314
- Part #: 0643-08-013

It looks like it was made by Robbins Myers Motor & Control Systems Division.

In case anyone is wondering, this motor comes from inside of a PUMA 560 robotic arm.

It also has an encoder/potentiometer attached to it which I am interested in getting datasheets for as well:

- esoline (? it's actually kind of hard to read the first character on the label) encoder.
- Type: P.4201717
- S. No.: 70754086
- 7223C30903

Any help in finding datasheets, or at the very least pinouts for either of these would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.cnczone.com/forums/servo_motors_drives/9435-techical_specification_electrocraft_0643-08-013_a.html

> I have the catalogue specs on
>   0643-31-011 & 0643-32-011 models,
>   these were the 0643 off-the-shelf
>   models and I believe the other numbers
>   are special order and may have been
>   just different mounts or shaft size
>   etc.
>   Al
>
> I will post them here in case someone
>   has the same question in the future.
>   Of the two models, one show the specs
>   in oz-in and the other in lb-in, but
>   converted they appear to be close to
>   the same.
>   0643-33-004
>   continuous stall 155 oz-in
>   pk torque 720 oz-in
>   max terminal voltage 60
>   max speed 4800 rpm
>   inertia .0304 oz-in-sec^
>   Kt 16.8 oz-in/amp
>   Ke 12.4 v/krpm
>   max pulse current 43 amp
>   Inductance .5mH
>
> 0643-32-004
>   continuous stall 9.7 lb-in
>   pk torque 45 lb-in
>   max terminal voltage 60
>   max speed 3700 rpm
>   inertia .0019 lb-in-sec^
>   Kt 1.34 lb-in/amp
>   Ke 15.9 v/krpm
>   max pulse current 33 amp
>   Inductance .8mH
>   Good luck
>   Al

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. For anyone who wants more info, I got pretty much the same answer plus more at http://www.reddit.com/r/robotics/comments/ee7ze/does_anyone_know_where_to_find_the_datasheet_for/c17hida